# looping into files having same string in second part of its name

Tags: shell

I am using loop instruction to zip many csv file based in their prefix (first element of its name)

```
 printf '%s\n' *_*.csv | cut -d_ -f1 | uniq |
    while read -r prefix
    do
      zip $ZIP_PATH/"$prefix"_"$DATE_EXPORT"_M2.zip "$prefix"_*.csv
    done
```

And it works very well, as an input I have

```
123_20211124_DONG.csv
123_20211124_FINA.csv
123_20211124_INDEM.csv
123_20211202_FINA.csv
123_20211202_INDEM.csv
```

and the zip loop will pack all these files because they have the same prefix
Or, I would like to pack only those which has $DATE_EXPORT= `20211202`, in other word, I want to pack only those which has second element in file **name=20211202**  == DATE_EXPORT variable
I tried using `grep` function like :

```
 printf '%s\n' *_*.csv | grep $DATE_EXPORT | cut -d_ -f1 | uniq |
    while read -r prefix
    do
      zip $ZIP_PATH/"$prefix"_"$DATE_EXPORT"_M2.zip "$prefix"_*.csv
    done
```

But, does not work, any help, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"$prefix"_*.csv` in the `zip` command in your second example is *not* filtered for `"$DATE_EXPORT"`. Try `"${prefix}_${DATE_EXPORT}_"*.csv` or similar. You can also use `*"_${DATE_EXPORT}_"*.csv` with `printf`, instead of `grep`.

Also, I'm not sure what's going on with `$cut`, but obviously `cut` is the usual name.

Comment: thank you I tested using, `cut` and not `$cut` , it was just copy error